# Call method on data state

Tags: vue.js

I need to call custom method in data initial state.

I defined a Mixin and after that I call my method:

```
const myMixin = {
 methods: {
   fillBrandsDropDownList() {
     return Nova.request().get('/nova-vendor/export/brands-list').then(response => {
        let brandNames = response.data.map(function (obj) {
          return {
            brand_name: obj.name,
          }
        });
      });
   }
 }
}


export default {
   mixins: [myMixin],
   data: function () {
     return {
       filter: null,
       brandNames: this.fillBrandsDropDownList(),
     };
   }
}
```

However the list doesn't populate

```
<ul>
   <li v-for="item in brandNames">
      {{ item.brand_name }}
   </li>
</ul>
```

I'm using vue.js inside Laravel Nova components.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return 'brandNames' after map info.

Notice: Also you can call this method in created() hooks before component mounted(). This useful to get response before initialize template.

Good luck

Comment: I also tryed to return brandsName after map info but still doesn't work : return Nova.request().get('/nova-vendor/export/brands-list').then(response => {

        let brandNames = response.data.map(function (obj) {
          return {
            brand_name: obj.name,
          }
        });


        return brandNames;
      });

Comment: This aproach is not recommended,  u better use second method. Call your method in created() section after that set brandnames from that response.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The error was that the api call needed the promise response. For this I created an "async" method that waits for the data to be returned before passing it to the list

```
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      filter: null,
      brandNames: null,
    };
  },
  created() {
   this.fetchBrandNames()
 },
 methods: {
   async fetchBrandNames() {
     const response = await Nova.request().get('/nova-vendor/export/brands-list');
     this.brandNames = response.data;
   }
 }
}
```